# Erro ao enviar informações para WebService: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException

Tags: c#, web-service

Criei um web service simples que faz uma soma de dois números e devolve o resultado. O `IIS` deixei configurado como autenticação windows habilitada e as outras desabilitadas.

Código:

```
  ServiceReference2.TesteSomaSoapClient a = new ServiceReference2.TesteSomaSoapClient();
  a.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = @ "Dominio\user";
  a.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "senha";

  var b = a.Soma(1, 1);
```

Tem me gerado o erro:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: A solicitação HTTP não está autorizada no esquema de autenticação de cliente 'Anonymous'. O cabeçalho de autenticação recebido do servidor foi 'Negotiate,NTLM'.

Mais um detalhe, nao vou poder enviar o usuario e senha. Teria como pegar o usuario corrente de quem esta chamando o web service?

Comment: Coloque seu Web.Config também.

Comment: A mesma coisa que está acontecendo contigo: ['System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752857/system-servicemodel-security-messagesecurityexception-in-wcf)

Comment: No meu consta este <binding>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>

Comment: Consegui pessoal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui pessoal

```
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

        basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

        basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:81/GravaSolicitacao.asmx");

        ServiceReference2.GravaSolicitacaoSoapClient client = new ServiceReference2.GravaSolicitacaoSoapClient(basicHttpBinding, endpoint);

        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

        client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        //var xx = client.Soma(4, 3);
        var xx = client.GravaSolic(1, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Comente a sua solução, por favor, não está claro o que foi alterado tendo em vista que o código postado na pergunta não está completo e o código da sua solução está totalmente diferente.